# Trading Simulation, compare 2 data frame : Python, Pandas, .loc .where

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration, trading

1. following are data what i am handling now
    [data image for easy understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcY9A.png)
2. following are code

   ```
   buying_list = data[data['Buying']==1]
   selling_list = data[data['Selling']==1]
   data['Cut_Off_Signal']=0


   # Buying & Selling & Cut off signal process
   def test(data):
       data_index = list(data.index)
       buying_list_index = list(buying_list.index)
       for i in range(len(data_index)):
           for j in range(len(buying_list_index)):
               if buying_list_index[j]<=data_index[i]:
                   #data.loc[(data['Cut_Off_Price'][j] < data['Close'][i]) & (data['Cut_Off_Price'][j] >= 1), 'Cut_Off_Signal'] = 1
                   data['Cut_Off_Signal'][i] = np.where((data['Cut_Off_Price'][j] < data['Close'][i]) & (data['Cut_Off_Price']>=1)  , 1, 0)
                   #data.loc[(data['Cut_Off_Price'][:i] < data['Close'][i]) & (data['Cut_Off_Price']!= 0), 'Cut_Off_Signal'] = 1
           return data
   ```
3. data

   ```
       Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close   Buying  Cut_Off_Price   Selling Cut_Off_Signal
   2015-10-13  256000  257000  255000  256000  161200  245982.6    0   0   0   0
   2015-10-14  257000  260000  256000  257500  147700  247423.91   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-15  257500  260500  256000  259000  139700  248865.21   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-16  258000  260000  256500  258000  120400  247904.34   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-19  258000  261500  257000  260500  89200   250306.52   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-20  258500  260500  257500  259500  93400   249345.65   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-21  260000  262000  259000  260000  93700   249826.08   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-22  259500  260000  250000  251500  192200  241658.69   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-23  252500  254500  249500  250000  147600  240217.39   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-26  252000  255500  251500  254000  160900  244060.87   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-27  254000  258500  251500  252000  149000  242139.13   1   228000  0   0
   2015-10-28  253000  254500  248500  249000  128000  239256.52   0   0   0   0
   2015-10-29  247500  250000  240000  242500  349000  233010.87   1   215050  0   0
   2015-10-30  243500  245500  241000  241000  250200  231569.56   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-02  243500  244000  235500  238500  541300  229167.39   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-03  237000  237500  224500  230000  1054600 221000  0   0   0   0
   2015-11-04  227500  237000  225500  231000  539400  221960.87   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-05  233000  234500  230500  230500  189300  221480.43   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-06  230500  231000  226000  227000  226700  218117.39   0   0   0   1
   2015-11-09  227000  231000  226500  229000  173100  220039.13   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-10  228500  229000  226000  227000  175000  218117.39   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-11  225500  233000  222500  229000  342700  220039.13   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-12  230000  234500  230000  232000  210700  222921.74   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-13  231000  235000  230000  232000  202700  222921.74   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-16  228000  234500  228000  233500  191300  224363.04   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-17  233500  234500  230500  231500  215400  222441.3    0   0   0   0
   2015-11-18  231000  232000  228000  230000  207000  221000  0   0   0   0
   2015-11-19  231500  233500  229500  232000  141900  222921.74   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-20  230000  233500  230000  233000  105600  223882.61   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-23  232000  232500  231000  232500  98700   223402.17   0   0   0   0
   2015-11-24  231000  233500  230500  233000  132100  223882.61   0   0   0   0
   ```
4. My desire result are

1) at everyday, compare close price and Cut_Off_Price

2) if close price are under Cut_Off_Price, then make Cut_Off_Signal "1"

3) and from the 2nd appearance of under Cut_Off_Price, then ignore. 
   (I didnt code yet, but i plan to erase this price in "buying_list"

above code didnt make any Cut_Off_Signal. could you advise??

4 i try to solve this problem but still failed.

```
    def test(data)
        for i in range(len(list(data.index))):
        data.loc[(data[:i][data['Buying']==1)['Cut_Off_Price']<=data['Close'][i],'Cut_Off_Signal']=1
        return data
```

facing error message are
 "IndexingError: Unalignalbe boolean Series key provided"

i really don't know what is the problem. your advice are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what you mean under point 3), but for 1) and 2) the code could look something like this:

```
data.loc[data.Cut_Off_Price>data.Close, 'Cut_Off_Signal'] = 1
```

Comment: I wanna check price everyday. If i apply ur advice then it will work at the first day. That is problem.

Comment: what my code does is, it checks for each row, whether the close price in that row is smaller than the cut_off_price in that row. For each row where that is the case, it writes a 1 into the cut_off_signal column. To me, that sounds like what you requested as each row represents one day.